# Adding a time delay to simulate lottery numbers being drawn

Tags: c++, timedelay

new to the forums here and beginning to learn C++.  This site has already helped me so much with syntax and other things.  What I'm trying to do with my code is have the number print to screen, have the time delay, then print the next number.  Currently the time delay works, but it prints all 13 numbers generated.  Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main( ) 
{

// Function prototypes
int random ( int minValue, int maxValue);

// Constant declarations
const int maxValue = 9;
const int minValue = 0;

// Local variable declarations
int seed;
int numberOfPeople;
int peopleCount = 0;
int numberCount;
int number;

 // Initialize the random number generator
 cout << "Welcome to the Lottery!" << endl;
 cout << "Enter your lucky number to start: " << endl;
 cin >> seed;
 srand (seed);   

 // Generate and display numbers
 cout << "Enter the number of people participating in the lottery:" << endl;
 cin >> numberOfPeople;

 cout << "Your lucky lottery numbers for the day are:" << endl;
 cout.setf (ios::left, ios::adjustfield);
 cout << setw(8) << "Pick 3" << setw(10) << "Pick 4" <<
   setw(15) << "Pick 6" << endl;

 while (peopleCount < numberOfPeople) {
   numberCount = 0;
      while (numberCount < 13){
         number =  random (minValue, maxValue);
         Sleep (500); // pauses for half a second
         cout << number << " ";

       if (numberCount == 2){
           cout << "  "; }
       else if (numberCount == 6){
           cout << "  ";       }
       else if (numberCount == 12){
           cout << endl;          } //end if, else if           

       numberCount++;     
     } //end nested while
  peopleCount++;
  } // end while

return 0;
} // end main()

/**
*  Produces a pseudo-random number
*  @param minValue    minimum value that can be generated
*  @param maxValue    maximum value that can be generated
*
*  @return         psuedo-random number in the specified range
*/

int random ( int minValue, // min possible number to be generated
        int maxValue)  // max possible number to be generated
{
return ( (rand() % maxValue) + minValue);
} // end random()
```

Comment: I recommend reading about the site. It's not a forum, and doesn't work like one. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Ok, thanks. I would still appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: The description of what you're trying to achieve is too vague. E.g. do you want a delay between each individual number or between each subsequent row of numbers? Or even between pick 3, 4 and 6?

Comment: I would like a delay between each individual number.  So the program would display the random number generated, wait for half a second and then display the next number.  I thought where I put the Sleep() would make it wait before it displayed the next number. If I wanted to wait between numbers, couldn't I just add the Sleep() in the if statements?

Answer (score 0):

cout is generally buffered, and the newline causes the buffer to be flushed to the screen.  As you display the numbers on the same line, this could explain that everything is displayed at onece despite the delay that you've build in.

Use [`cout.flush();`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/) to force output to be done without buffering delay.  You could as well use the [manipulator form](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/flush-free/): `cout << number << " " << flush;`